# PHP mail: attachement sent but won't open

Tags: php

The mail works well and I receive it in my mailbox and I receive the attachment too but I can't opent it, and I'm really in a situation that I can't use any library like `SwiftMailer` or `PHPMailer` so I need to make this work.
This is my code:

```
function mail_attachment($to, $subject, $msg, $from, $file) {
        $file_size = filesize($file);
        $handle = fopen($file, "r");
        $content = fread($handle, $file_size);
        fclose($handle);

        $content = chunk_split(base64_encode(file_get_contents($file)));
        $uid = md5(uniqid(time()));

        $eol = PHP_EOL;

        // Basic headers
        $header = "From: Equipe Grifoflex <".$from.">".$eol;
        $header .= "Reply-To: ".$to.$eol;
        $header .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
        $header .= "Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"".$uid."\"";

        // Put everything else in $message
        $message = "--".$uid.$eol;
        $message .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1".$eol;
        $message .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit".$eol.$eol;
        $message .= $msg.$eol;
        $message .= "--".$uid.$eol;
        $message .= "Content-Type: application/pdf; name=\"".$file."\"".$eol;
        $message .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64".$eol;
        $message .= "Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"".$file."\"".$eol;
        $message .= $content.$eol;
        $message .= "--".$uid."--";

        return mail($to, $subject, $message, $header);
    }
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: It could be as simple as a missing new line or the wrong `PHP_EOL`. Sending mails with attachments is tricky. I would use a library for this, like PHPMailer, or similar.

Comment: @RyanVincent thanks for your answer but as I said my code works fine and send the email with the attachment, the only problem is that I can't open the file when I receive it, I guess maybe it's a codage problem but I'm not sure !!